# Executable compiled by visual studio freezes

Tags: windows, visual-studio, exe

I made a simple project with Visual Studio, but when I try to run it, Visual studio freezes and I have to shut it down. If I launch the executable directly with the explorer, the explorer freezes. I've tried with visual studio 2010, 2013 and 2015, it always freezes.
Dependancy walker find no errors in it. I've sent it to a friend, and he manages to launch it on its computer. I've also tried to run in as administrator, still nothing.

I've tried this on several projects, even some of them that worked years ago, but I still have the problem.

My OS is Windows 10, with the Threshold 2 update.

Comment: We've been having this question asked all week.  Uninstall Avast.

Comment: Well. Thanks a lot I was trying to solve this issue since this morning.